# Adding parameters to arraylist with Java

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am testing my college class and when the user types in "add" it adds a new student to the arraylist in the college class.

```
   Scanner myInput=new Scanner (System.in);
   String information=myInput.next(); //I know this is incorrect not sure what else to do
    directory.addStudent(information);
```

here the directory is the object of the arraylist containing students. the addStudent method is in the College class, and looks like this:

```
  public void addStudent (String studentName, long studentID, String address) {
        Student newStu= new Student( studentname, studentID, address);
        collegeList.add(newStu); //here collegeList is the name of the arraylist in College class
   }
```

anyways my question seems simple but can't figure it out. I want to know how to split the information so that it can satisfy the parameters in addStudent method...As you can see information will be a String but I want studentID to be a long not a string what can I do?

Comment: Take a look at the various `X.parseX()` methods where X are the common subtypes of `Number`.

Comment: Provide some information about your inputs. how name, id and address are separated in input? By newline? whitespace? comma?

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the string after reading is not necessary. You can read delimited string using Scanner.

I assume your inputs are separated by whitespace. If so, you need to do this:

```
    String name = myInput.next();
    long id = myInput.nextLong();
    String address = myInput.next();
    dictionary.add(name, id, address);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentMain {
    private static List<Student> collegeList = new ArrayList<Student> (); 
    public static void main(String...args)throws Throwable {
         String s= null; String name=null; long id=0L; String address = null; 
        System.out.print("What do you want to do today, press q to quit : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
        try{    
                s = sc.next();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
                    System.out.print("Enter the name of student:  ");
                    name = sc.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter the Id of student : " );
                    id=sc.nextLong();
                    System.out.print("Enter address of student:  ");
                    address = sc.next();
                    addStudent(name,id,address);
                }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            if(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
                System.out.println("Please enter q to quit else try again ==> ");
            }
        }while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
    sc.close();
    }
    private static void addStudent(String name, long id, String address) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Student newStu = new Student(name,id,address);
        collegeList.add(newStu);        
    }

}

class Student{
    String name;
    Long id;
    String address;

    Student(String name,Long id,String address){
    this.name= name;
    this.id = id;
    this.address=address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method to break your information

What you have to do is

```
String str = new String(information);
String[] s = str.split(" ", 3);
```

i am splitting on the space basis , second argument 3 means you have to break into 3 strings i.e name,id,address

after this you can get `name via s[0] , id via s[1] and address via s[2]`
so you can pass easily over `addStudent()` method . but you need to convert the values according to the arguments of `addStudent()` method